# How to pass a variable into %0 part of batch file with ftp?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp

I have a batch file I want to be able to call from the command line like:

```
myBatch.bat testParam
```

That batch file is the following:

```
set sid=%1

C:\Windows\System32\ftp.exe -s:%0
goto done
open servername
username
password
get 'FilePath%sid%restoffilepath' targetPath\%sid%MyName.txt
bye
:done
```

However, I cannot seem to get the `FilePath%sid%restoffilepath` part to work right - I believe it is because the `%0` is treating the input as literal, but I'm not 100% sure. The %sid% variable is not expanded.

I basically want to have `FilePath%sid%restoffilepath` be `FilePathtestParamrestoffilepath` in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think carefully about what you are doing here--the ftp.exe is reading the file.  Your batch script, which knows what %1 is, is not feeding the data to ftp.exe.

What you need to do is to shoot the script out to a file, and then run the ftp command:

```
set sid=%1

echo open servername >> myftp.txt
echo username >> myftp.txt
echo password >> myftp.txt
echo get 'FilePath%sid%restoffilepath' targetPath\%sid%MyName.txt >> myftp.txt
echo bye >> myftp.txt

C:\Windows\System32\ftp.exe -s:myftp.txt
```

Comment: This was... obvious. Doh. :)

Comment: @Tony Please give your inputs on [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297207/2246380) question about one of your suggested edits in meta.